# Secure cat local host's file to a remote host

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-access

Is there a way to secure append text to a file on remote machine?
Without actually copying over the file as such.

At the moment, I need to do a secure copy, then cat and append. Any way directly append securely?

Any help is great, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cat /local/file.txt | ssh user@remote.host 'cat >> /remote/file.txt'
```

ssh passes its stdin to remote commands, so the remote `cat` sees the piped output of the local `cat`. Nifty.

Comment: quick question: if I were to do this in another _master_ shell, it's giving a permission denied error. What'd you suggest for this?

Comment: What command are you doing? I don't know what you mean by 'another master shell'.